# Where can I check if my vehicle has a manufacturers recall for a defect?

Tags: recall, manufacturer

I am interested in recall information from Europe, Asia, North and South America in order to enter the various information into a site wiki for the community.

I'm not sure if I should post this question in meta or in here.  Regardless, if the question is answered here, it will be here.

Please post your answers with URL's and when there is an accumulation I will make a wiki page and include all of the valid links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The United States government has placed authority for recall's and manufacturer interaction under the National Transportation and Safety Board (NTSB).  A sub of the NTSB is the National Highway Traffic Safety Administration (NHTS), which is where this website is located.

This link is for the United States Only.

[**Search for Recalls Here**](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/owners/SearchSafetyIssues)

**You can search by**

- VIN
- Manufacturer, Model and Year

Various regulations by localities make recalls individual by country.  I believe in Europe there is a central authority under the EU that now handles recalls but my research has failed me and I am unable to state that as a fact.  I'll let more intimate resources vet that out with there responses.